# how do you add a option were when you hover over a floating action button it changes the color like a filter

Tags: javascript, css, material-ui

I never used a `<Fab />` before but I'm confused on how to add a hover option that changes the buttons color. So far i have this:

js:

```
<Fab variant="extended" className="sidebar__tweet" fullWidth>
  <TwitterIcon className= 'sidebar__twitterIcon2' sx={{ mr: 1 }} />
  Tweet
</Fab>
```

css:

```
sidebar__tweet:
.sidebar__tweet {
        background-color: var(--twitter-color) !important;
        border: none !important;
        color: #444444 !important;
        font-weight: 900 !important;
        text-transform: inherit  !important;
        border-radius:  30px !important;
        height: 50px !important;
        margin-top: 20px !important;
    }
sidebar__TweetIcon2:
    .sidebar__twitterIcon2 {
        color: #444444;
    }
```

if i add a new css function that changes the hover color it errases the other styleings of the button and goes back to default

Comment: Is it actually bootstrap or is it [mui](https://mui.com/components/floating-action-button/)?

Comment: i got the code from mui just thought bootstrap would work with it

Answer (score 0):

`<Fab />` comes with hover color based on the [`color`](https://mui.com/api/fab/#:%7E:text=The%20color%20of%20the%20component.%20It%20supports%20those%20theme%20colors%20that%20make%20sense%20for%20this%20component.) prop.

If you want to override the color, you can use the [`sx` prop](https://mui.com/system/the-sx-prop/).

```js
<Fab
  color="primary"
  aria-label="add"
  sx={{
    border: '3px solid orange',
    ":hover": {
      background: "linear-gradient(45deg, #FE6B8B 30%, #FF8E53 90%)"
    }
  }}
>
  <TwitterIcon sx={{ mr: 1 }} />
</Fab>
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/fab-custom-hover-effect-gqhrt?file=/demo.js